# How to enable wagering/prediction in dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I can't predict or wager in Dota 2. How to enable wagering? So I can predict and win wagering points.

Answer (score 2):

#### Wagering

This is something that can only be done with the [Winter Battle Pass](http://www.dota2.com/winter2016).

This allows players to bet, using tokens*, at the beginning of games. If they go on to win the game they will obtain battle points, which level up the Winter Battle Pass.

<sub>*Players get given 1000 tokens each week to bet with.</sub>

#### Predictions

There are currently two ways players can make predictions on games:

- Using the [Assured Victory Shout](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Assured_Victory_Shout), which was obtained from the, no longer obtainable, [International Compendium 2014](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/The_International_Compendium_2014). Or,
- Using [charms](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Charms) for the chance to win a treasure* after 3 successful predictions. These are currently obtained by purchasing them from the store / market place, such as the [Charm of the Autumn Flurry](http://www.dota2.com/store/itemdetails/11377).

<sub>* From some charms it was possible to get [Arcanas](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Charm_of_the_Crucible_Jewel_II) or [coins](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Coin_Charm_-_Fall_2015), but are no longer obtainable.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Wagering is something which compendium owner can do. Compendium allows a person to bet and win points along the game. These points level up your compendium and you receive your awards accordingly. Current compendium in dota 2 is winter battle pass.

Predictions is something which a gem owners can do. Valve often releases prediction gems in which when you win 3 times you get a treasure.

Make sure you buy compendium or gems to enable wagering or prediction.

Note:- gems can also be obtained when s person recycles 10 items.

Comment: It's actually the battle pass for the winter season/Shanghai major period that allows you to wager, not necessarily the compendium (yet the compendium is bundled when you buy the battle pass).

Answer (score 0):

About wagering, you have to own the battle pass in order to wage your points. Then, you can wage after hero selection.

About predict, you have to recycle a few of your items to obtain an item that will allow you to predict, or you can buy the item at the store.

Answer (score -1):

Just buy the compendium, and you can wager every week 1000 :).
The predition is another thing.
You can buy compendium here :http://www.dota2.com/international/battlepass

Comment: You should explain what the compendium is and what it does